# What were the Top 10 Shuttle Risks in John Young's "famous letter"?

Tags: space-shuttle, history, safety, external-tank

Whilst reading *[A Technical History of the External Tank](https://www.nasa.gov/externalflash/irkm-slwt/Resources/SLWT_Lessons_Learned.pdf)* I ran across this comment:

> Although  the  problem  has  not  recurred,  [John  Young](https://www.nasa.gov/sites/default/files/atoms/files/young_john.pdf),  in  his
> famous  top  ten  Shuttle  risk  letter  published  after  the
> Challenger  accident,  listed   stiction as a significant risk.

What were the top ten risks listed by Young<sup>1</sup>? Preferably, with the full text of the "letter".

I remember him being famous for issuing memos about Shuttle safety, but I don't remember this one.

<sup>1</sup>Ok, the other nine.

An acceptable answer to this question must include all three of the following elements:

- Be a list of shuttle **risks**
- Be written, or at least sent out, by John Young
- **Include ET pressure transducer stiction as one of the risks**

Comment: Haven't found the document, but footnote 63 [here](https://history.nasa.gov/SP-4219/Chapter15.html#Chapt15-63) gives a possible title: *Memorandum from CB/Chief, Astronaut Office to CA/Director, Flight Crew Operations, "One Part of the 51-L Accident-Space Shuttle Program Flight Safety"*.

Comment: I found several contemporary news articles about it - Truly released the memo in March 1986 - but the 'top ten list' seems to have been an attachment that is mentioned, but not shown in the articles. Here's one such that mentions a few issues: https://apnews.com/ccb0ae4d23f23b581d9b601fd833fcf8

Comment: I have found the original memo you're talking about.  No "top ten" list.  See https://history.nasa.gov/SP-4407/vol4/cover.pdf page 378 has the memo.  Also, stiction is not mentioned in the memo.  There is a list of safety questions that Young raised that are interesting, but not set out as a list I'm afraid.  It seems that another document is the one that contains the list...

Comment: That's super interesting! But I think the answer must include a list that includes stiction. So maybe the news articles were talking about a different memo.

Comment: Indeed.  To clarify, I was talking about the memo mentioned in the comments, so yes, it looks like it isn't the one you were looking for

Comment: Got it, thanks!

Comment: Here's the author (Myron Pessin) mentioning John Young's opinions about ejection seats and the propellant dispersion systems in an interview: https://historycollection.jsc.nasa.gov/JSCHistoryPortal/history/oral_histories/STS-R/PessinMA/PessinMA_6-30-10.htm (ctrl+f "John [W.] Young")

Comment: I guess I have some reading to do then.

Comment: @SE-stopfiringthegoodguys speaking of reading, I should read my own question. Doh! There's a link to it there.

Comment: I can't add a comment but so far I found this pdf from NASA. https://www.govinfo.gov/content/pkg/GPO-CRPT-99hrpt1016/pdf/GPO-CRPT-99hrpt1016.pdf

Comment: @Lucas Can you expand on how this is relevant? That's a 450 page document, what were you trying to point out?

Comment: @OrganicMarble If you truly decide that this document is not available, you could consider filing a FOIA request with NASA.

Comment: @user16338 apparently it was published in the now defunct newspaper the Houston Post. The downtown Houston library has archives of the paper on microfiche, once they open back up (currently closed for pandemic) I plan to go look for it.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to find a [news article](https://apnews.com/article/ccb0ae4d23f23b581d9b601fd833fcf8) that addresses some of this.

Booster rocket seal conditions

> ... Challenger flight that exploded and killed its crew of seven, Young said, ″There is only one driving reason that such a potentially dangerous system would ever be allowed to fly - launch schedule pressure.″

Space shuttle launch rate

> we should not allow any increase in the inherent risk of operating the space shuttle just to increase the launch rate, or reduce operating costs, or fly unsafe payloads.

Flapper valves

> October-December 1984 - Flapper valves on fittings between the shuttle and its huge liquid fuel tank were ″extremely sensitive.″ If any of the four flapper valves close, the memo said, ″the result is loss of vehicle and crew.″

Adverse weather and tile damage

> August 1985 - The shuttle Discovery was launched at a time when there was moderate turbulence and rain on an emergency landing runway at the Kennedy Space Center. ″If the tile damage assessment was realistic, winds in storms plus tile damage drag might lose the vehicle and crew in an abort″ .

Lock up of maneuvering jets

> October 1985 - A regulator on one of Challenger’s maneuvering jets locked up. ″The cause of the lockup was not known,″ according to the memo. NASA decided to fly anyway, relying on another backup regulator, which also ″indicated failed″ as it reached orbit.

Failure of a liquid oxygen prevalve

> January 1986 - A delay in launching Columbia revealed a critical failure of a liquid oxygen prevalve.

Comment: I'm not sure if [this](https://www.ebay.com/itm/324371844039?nma=true&si=TPMoEjAk256eLXZNFhNusP3gK94%253D&orig_cvip=true&nordt=true&rt=nc&_trksid=p2047675.l2557) is the one or another one.

Comment: I'm glad you posted this because it reminded me to check on the status of the 2 downtown Houston libraries that have Houston Post archives. It seems that they are open to the public now, so perhaps I can get down there later this week.